# JS: How to compare 2 dates converting from UTC to defined timezone?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I stored a string of UTC Date (without time):

```
var limitDateStr = "2017-07-04T00:00:00.000Z";
```

And a TIMEZONE in hours [(based on this)](https://gist.github.com/jonathanforsythe/1065260), not in Zone Name (like America/Antigua)

```
var timezone = "-6.0"; //could be from -12.0 to 12.0
```

The problem is: **Verify if actual date, is greater than limitDate in the same Timezone.**

---

**What I Do with Moment.js**

I Used moment for change the timezone, but when y change the offset. The date is changed too:

```
  var _expirationDateUTC = moment.utc(limitDateStr).utcOffset(parseFloat(timezone)).format();
  // "2017-07-03T18:00:00-06:00"
```

Instead of `2017-07-04T00:00:00-06:00`

Actual date, works great: (except for Days Savings)

```
var today = moment.utc().utcOffset(parseFloat(timezone)).format();
//"2017-07-04T15:32:49-06:00"
```

And I want to compare... maybe with moment function:

```
today.isAfter(_expirationDateUTC);
```

but the expiration date is now working like expect.

Comment: By "actual date" you mean "current date"?

Comment: If you reduce everything to UTC then you can forget timezones. If time A is before time B in a particular timezone, then A is always before B in any timezone. If you change the timezone offset of a timestamp, it will represent a different moment in time.

Comment: @Bergi yes sir, current date. Sorry my english is not so good.

Comment: @RobG , the BD keep UTC value, but what if you need infor from Chile, or from Spain. The information is equivalent but in different time. This is for a promo, if is about an international promo, you can't restrict to UTC because is not equitative situation in different country.  (Ignore proxies and things like that)

Comment: @elporfirio—"2017-07-04T00:00:00.000Z" represents a specific moment in time. If you shift the offset to -0600, then the equivalent timestamp is "2017-07-03T18:00:00.000-0600". A common strategy is to keep everything as UTC and convert to whatever timezone for display only. So if a user inputs "2017-07-03T18:00:00.000-0600" (or equivalent) it's stored as "2017-07-04T00:00:00.000Z". A user in timezone +1000 would see it as "2017-07-04T10:00:00.000+1000". They are all exactly the same moment in time.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there problem seems to be this:

```
var _expirationDateUTC = moment.utc(limitDateStr).utcOffset(parseFloat(timezone)).format();
```

where `limitDateStr = "2017-07-04T00:00:00.000Z"`;

What you are doing up to this point is feeding moment with this date and then apply the timezone offset, which will substract the timezone(in this case -6) to the date you are actually feeding.

"2017-07-04T00:00:00.000Z" - 6 hours = "2017-07-03T18:00:00-06:00"

What you are looking for is not to calculate the limitDate in a different timezone but to have limitDate to be the same as the utc but in a different timezone.

So you need this block of code which will add the hours from the target zone:

```
var limitDateStr = moment("2017-07-04T00:00:00.000Z");
var timezone = "-6.0"

//Substract the timezone offset to the time;
//This should be: "2017-07-04T06:00:00.000Z"
limitDateStr.subtract({hours: parseFloat(timezone)});

//Now you can apply the offseting
//and this will become: "2017-07-04T00:00:00-06:00"
var _expirationDateUTC = moment.utc(limitDateStr).utcOffset(parseFloat(timezone)).format();

var today = moment.utc().utcOffset(parseFloat(timezone)).format();

var hasExpired = today.isAfter(_expirationDateUTC);
```

Answer (score 0):

Primitive solution was: "add the difference in hours"

```
function validateDateBefore(date, timezone){
  /** enable this for end day limit **/
  //var _expirationDateUTC = moment.utc(date).utcOffset(parseFloat(timezone)).startOf('hour').add((parseFloat(timezone) * -1) + 23, 'hours').add(59, 'minute').add(59, 'second').format();
  var _expirationDateUTC = moment.utc(date).utcOffset(parseFloat(timezone)).startOf('hour').add((parseFloat(timezone) * -1), 'hours').format();
  var _todayUTC = moment.utc().utcOffset(parseFloat(timezone)).format();

  var today = moment(_todayUTC);
  var expiration = moment(_expirationDateUTC);

  return expiration.isAfter(today);
}
```